# Двухмерная поверхность из сетки не превращается в трёхмерную с помощью шейдера Python Pyopengl

Tags: python, c++, opengl, матрицы, графика

Задача такова:
имеется сетка из квадратов размера N
каждая вершина квадрата это... вершина, точка, с координатами X и Z (это массив вершин. Для его обхода также используется массив индексов)
необходимо эту сетку превратить в трёхмерную с помощью функции Y = f(X,Z) внутри шейдера

для этого также необходимо сместить сетку "вверх" по Z и немного "влево" по X, а также уменьшить её размер (см.скриншот)
матрица модели составляется перемножением матриц поворота (R), масштабирования (S) и переноса (T),
а затем всё умножается на матрицу проекции (P)
Цвет для каждой точки вычисляется при помощи градиента. Класс, как на скриншоте, я не создавал, это опционально
[image]

вроде бы всё сделал, как надо, но не работает. Поверхность не меняется.
За основу взял чужой код на C++, чтобы построить точно такую же поверхность, а затем уже подобрать свою. Вот сам чужой код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp"
#include "glm/mat4x4.hpp"
#include "glm/matrix.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"

#include <math.h> 
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

GLFWwindow *g_window;

GLuint g_shaderProgram;
GLint g_uMVP;
GLint g_uMV;
GLint g_uMN;

chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> g_callTime;

float rot = 0;

class Point
{
public:
    GLint x;
    GLint z;
};

class Model
{
public:
    GLuint vbo;
    GLuint ibo;
    GLuint vao;
    GLsizei indexCount;
};

Model g_model;

GLuint createShader(const GLchar *code, GLenum type)
{
    GLuint result = glCreateShader(type);

    glShaderSource(result, 1, &code, NULL);
    glCompileShader(result);

    GLint compiled;
    glGetShaderiv(result, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);

    if (!compiled)
    {
        GLint infoLen = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(result, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);
        if (infoLen > 0)
        {
            char* infoLog = new char[infoLen];
            glGetShaderInfoLog(result, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);
            cout << "Shader compilation error" << endl << infoLog << endl;
            delete[] infoLog;
        }
        glDeleteShader(result);
        return 0;
    }

    return result;
}

GLuint createProgram(GLuint vsh, GLuint fsh)
{
    GLuint result = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(result, vsh);
    glAttachShader(result, fsh);

    glLinkProgram(result);

    GLint linked;
    glGetProgramiv(result, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);

    if (!linked)
    {
        GLint infoLen = 0;
        glGetProgramiv(result, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);
        if (infoLen > 0)
        {
            char *infoLog = (char *)alloca(infoLen);
            glGetProgramInfoLog(result, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);
            cout << "Shader program linking error" << endl << infoLog << endl;
        }
        glDeleteProgram(result);
        return 0;
    }

    return result;
}

bool createShaderProgram()
{
    g_shaderProgram = 0;

    const GLchar vsh[] =
        "#version 330\n"
        ""
        "layout(location = 0) in vec2 a_position;"
        "layout(location = 1) in vec3 a_color;"
        ""
        "uniform mat4 u_mvp;"
        "uniform mat3 u_mn;"
        ""
        "out vec3 v_color;"
        ""
        "void main()"
        "{"
        "    float x = a_position.x;"
        "    float z = a_position.y;"
        "    float y = 20 * atan((x - 50) * (z - 50));"
        "    float dx = abs(-20 * (-50 + z) / (1 + (-50 + x) * (-50 + x) * (-50 + z) * (-50 + z)));"
        "    float dz = abs(-20 * (-50 + x) / (1 + (-50 + x) * (-50 + x) * (-50 + z) * (-50 + z)));"
        "    float dy = 1.0;"
        "    v_color = normalize(u_mn * vec3(dx, dy, dz));"
        "    gl_Position = u_mvp * vec4(x, y, z, 1.0);"
        "}"
        ;

    const GLchar fsh[] =
        "#version 330\n"     
        ""
        "in vec3 v_color;"
        ""
        "layout(location = 0) out vec4 o_color;"
        ""
        "void main()"
        "{"
        "   o_color = vec4(v_color, 1.0);"
        "}"
        ;

    GLuint vertexShader, fragmentShader;

    vertexShader = createShader(vsh, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShader = createShader(fsh, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    g_shaderProgram = createProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);

    g_uMVP = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgram, "u_mvp");
    g_uMN = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgram, "u_mn");

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    return g_shaderProgram != 0;
}

bool createModel()
{
    const GLint n = 100;

    // Создание сетки

    GLfloat *vertices = new GLfloat[n * n * 2];

    // Заполнение массива вершин
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int coord = 2 * (i * n + j);    // i * n - "строка", j - "столбец"
            vertices[coord] = j;            // x
            vertices[coord + 1] = i;        // z
        }

    GLuint *indices = new GLuint[(n - 1) * (n - 1) * 6];

    // Заполнение массива индексов
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            int coordInd = 6 * (i * (n - 1) + j);       // индекс в массиве индексов
            int coordCurLine = i * n + j;               // вершины текущей линии в сетке
            int coordNextLine = (i + 1) * n + j;        // вершины следующей линии в сетке
            indices[coordInd] = coordCurLine;
            indices[coordInd + 1] = coordCurLine + 1;
            indices[coordInd + 2] = coordNextLine + 1;
            indices[coordInd + 3] = coordNextLine + 1;
            indices[coordInd + 4] = coordNextLine;
            indices[coordInd + 5] = coordCurLine;
        }

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &g_model.vao);
    glBindVertexArray(g_model.vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &g_model.vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_model.vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2 * n * n * sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    delete[] vertices;

    glGenBuffers(1, &g_model.ibo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_model.ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * (n - 1) * (n - 1) * sizeof(GLuint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    g_model.indexCount = 6 * (n - 1) * (n - 1);

    delete[] indices;

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), (const GLvoid *)0);

    return g_model.vbo != 0 && g_model.ibo != 0 && g_model.vao != 0;
}

bool init()
{
    // Set initial color of color buffer to white.
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    return createShaderProgram() && createModel();
}

void reshape(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void draw(float delta)
{
    int w = 0, h = 0;

    // Clear color buffer.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(g_shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(g_model.vao);

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(g_window, &w, &h);

    // Матрица перспективной проекции
    glm::mat4 p = glm::perspective(
        glm::radians(40.0f),            // вертикальное поле зрения
        (float)w / h,                   // отношение сторон
        0.1f,                           // ближняя плоскость отсечения
        100.0f                          // дальняя плоскость отсечения
    );

    // Матрица вида 
    glm::mat4 v = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0),      // позиция камеры 
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),    // направление взгляда
        glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)        // направление вверх
    );

    // Матрица модели
    glm::mat4 m = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0029f, 0.0029f, 0.0029f));    // масштабирование
    m = glm::translate(m, glm::vec3(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f));                                // перенос
    m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(-20.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));              // поворот
    
    rot = fmod(rot, 360) + 50.0f * delta;

    m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(rot), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));                    // вращение

    glm::mat4 mv = v * m;
    glm::mat3 mn = glm::transpose(glm::inverse(glm::mat3(mv)));                         // матрица нормалей
    glm::mat4 mvp = p * mv;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(g_uMVP, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvp));
    glUniformMatrix3fv(g_uMN, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mn));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, g_model.indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
}

void cleanup()
{
    if (g_shaderProgram != 0)
        glDeleteProgram(g_shaderProgram);
    if (g_model.vbo != 0)
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &g_model.vbo);
    if (g_model.ibo != 0)
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &g_model.ibo);
    if (g_model.vao != 0)
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &g_model.vao);
}

bool initOpenGL()
{
    // Initialize GLFW functions.
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize GLFW" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Request OpenGL 3.3 without obsoleted functions.
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Create window.
    g_window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL Test", NULL, NULL);
    if (g_window == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed to open GLFW window" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return false;
    }

    // Initialize OpenGL context with.
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(g_window);

    // Set internal GLEW variable to activate OpenGL core profile.
    glewExperimental = true;

    // Initialize GLEW functions.
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed.
    glfwSetInputMode(g_window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    // Set callback for framebuffer resizing event.
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(g_window, reshape);

    return true;
}

void tearDownOpenGL()
{
    // Terminate GLFW.
    glfwTerminate();
}

int main()
{
    // Initialize OpenGL
    if (!initOpenGL())
        return -1;

    // Initialize graphical resources.
    bool isOk = init();

    g_callTime = chrono::system_clock::now();

    if (isOk)
    {
        // Main loop until window closed or escape pressed.
        while (glfwGetKey(g_window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(g_window) == 0)
        {
            auto callTime = chrono::system_clock::now();
            chrono::duration<double> elapsed = callTime - g_callTime;
            g_callTime = callTime;

            //m = glm::rotate(m, glm::radians(30.0f * (float) elapsed.count()), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));

            // Draw scene.
            draw(elapsed.count());

            // Swap buffers.
            glfwSwapBuffers(g_window);
            // Poll window events.
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    // Cleanup graphical resources.
    cleanup();

    // Tear down OpenGL.
    tearDownOpenGL();

    return isOk ? 0 : -1;
}
```

Вот результаты работы этого кода (там происходит анимация, и это только один её кадр):
[image]

А вот мой код на Python:

```
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
import numpy  # numpy необходим для применения vertices и indices
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileProgram, compileShader  # для работы с шейдерами достаточно этих двух функций
import pyrr  # для работы с матрицами

N = 100

start_width = 800
start_height = 600

projection_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(60, start_width / start_height, 0.01, 200)  # матрица проекции


def window_resize(window, width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

    global projection_matrix
    projection_matrix = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(60, width / height, 0.01, 200)
    print(projection_matrix)


# создание списка вершин
vertices = []
i = 0
j = 0
while i < N:
    while j < N:
        vertices.append(j)  # x
        vertices.append(i)  # z
        j = j + 1
    j = 0
    i = i + 1

# создание списка индексов
indices = []
i = 0
a = i
j = 0
while i < N - 1:
    while j < N - 1:
        indices.append(a)
        indices.append(a + 1)
        indices.append(N + a + 1)
        indices.append(N + a + 1)
        indices.append(N + a)
        indices.append(a)
        j = j + 1
        a = a + 1
    j = 0
    i = i + 1
    a = N * i

vertex_shader = """
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec2 a_position;
uniform mat4 u_mvp;
uniform mat3 u_normals;
out vec3 v_color;

void main()
{
    float x = a_position.x;
    float z = a_position.y;
    float y = 20 * atan((x - 50) * (z - 50));
    float dx = abs(-20 * (-50 + z) / (1 + (-50 + x) * (-50 + x) * (-50 + z) * (-50 + z)));
    float dz = abs(-20 * (-50 + x) / (1 + (-50 + x) * (-50 + x) * (-50 + z) * (-50 + z)));
    float dy = 1.0;
    v_color = normalize(u_normals * vec3(dx, dy, dz));
    gl_Position = u_mvp * vec4(x, y, z, 1.0);
}
"""

fragment_shader = """
#version 330

in vec3 v_color;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 o_color;

void main()
{
    o_color = vec4(v_color, 1.0);
}
"""

# инициализируем GLFW
if not glfw.init():
    raise Exception("GLFW не может быть инициализован")

window = glfw.create_window(start_width, start_height, "OpenGL Test", None, None)  # создаём окно
if not window:  # не создалось, значит освобождаем память
    glfw.terminate()
    raise Exception("GLFW окно почему-то не создаётся")

glfw.set_window_pos(window, 400, 200)  # устанавливаем позицию относительно левого верхнего угла
glfw.make_context_current(window)  # контекст окна делаем текущим
glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)  # цвет очистки - белый
glfw.set_input_mode(window, glfw.STICKY_KEYS, glfw.TRUE)  # улавливаем нажатия клавиш
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)  # запускаем тесты глубины

# конвертируем списки через numpy в массивы numpy для дальнейшей работы
vertices = numpy.array(vertices, dtype=numpy.float32)
indices = numpy.array(indices, dtype=numpy.uint32)

# засовываем их в видеопамять:

model_vbo = glGenBuffers(1)  # генерируем один буфер вершин
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, model_vbo)  # биндим этот буфер на роль массива / буфера вершин
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.nbytes, vertices,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW)  # из оперативной памяти в видеокарту, размер данных вычисляем с помощью свойства nbites

model_ibo = glGenBuffers(1)  # генерируем один буфер индексов
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model_ibo)  # биндим этот буфер на роль массива / буфера индексов
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.nbytes, indices,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW)  # из оперативной памяти в видеокарту, размер данных вычисляем с помощью свойства nbites

# храним данные в формате XY (атрубут 0):
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)  # ВКЛ атрибут 0
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * 4, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
# размер GL_FLOAT определён заранее (4 байта) т.к. я не нашёл подходящей работающей функции вычисления размера GL_FLOAT (внезапно)
# c_void_p это функция из Си, позволяющая создавать указатель, а ctypes необходим для доступа к функциям Си

# компилируем оба шейдера
shaders = compileProgram(compileShader(vertex_shader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                         compileShader(fragment_shader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))

glUseProgram(shaders)  # запускаем шейдеры

glfw.set_window_size_callback(window, window_resize)  # устанавливаем коллбэк для смены матрицы проекции

translation_matrix = [
    [1, 0, 0, -25],
    [0, 1, 0, 30],
    [0, 0, 1, -10],
    [0, 0, 0, 1]
]  # матрица переноса
scale_matrix = [
    [2, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1]
]   # матрица масштабирования

# конвертируем списки через numpy в массивы numpy для дальнейшей работы
translation_matrix = numpy.array(translation_matrix, dtype=numpy.float32)
scale_matrix = numpy.array(scale_matrix, dtype=numpy.float32)

# связываем переменные из оперативной памяти и из видеопамяти
mvp_location = glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "u_mvp")
m_normals_location = glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "u_normals")

# главный цикл
while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)  # сообщаем, что необходимо обновить цвет и глубину
    glfw.poll_events()  # отловка событий

    # матрица поворота. Она внутри цикла из-за анимации вращения
    #x_rotation = pyrr.Matrix44.from_x_rotation(glfw.get_time())
    #y_rotation = pyrr.Matrix44.from_y_rotation(glfw.get_time())
    #rotation_matrix = x_rotation

    mv = scale_matrix

    mv = numpy.matmul(translation_matrix, mv)
    #mv = numpy.matmul(rotation_matrix, mv)
    mvp = numpy.matmul(projection_matrix, mv)
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_location, 1, GL_FALSE, mvp.ravel())  # посылаем данные в вершинный шейдер

    mv33 = numpy.array(mv, dtype=numpy.float32)
    mv33 = mv33[numpy.array([0, 1, 2])[:, numpy.newaxis], numpy.array([0, 1, 2])]  # образка матрицы 44 до 33
    m_normals = numpy.transpose(numpy.linalg.inv(mv33))  # матрица нормалей
    glUniformMatrix3fv(m_normals_location, 1, GL_FALSE, m_normals.ravel())  # посылаем данные в вершинный шейдер

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, len(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)
    glfw.swap_buffers(window)  # двойная буферизация

# завершаем GLFW. Занятые ресурсы вжух и освобождаются
glfw.terminate()
```

В результате получается не то, что нужно, не такая же поверхность. Даже не близко:
[image]

Мне главное, чтобы поверхность получилась примерно такой же, а с её размерами, поворотами, местоположением я сам разберусь.
Массив вершин вроде как получился корректным, массив индексов тоже, вид у матриц тоже соответствующий, шейдеры одинаковые (за исключением одной строки с layout 1, но она не нужна и это должна быть небольшая ошибка автора кода на С++), но всё равно не работает.
P. S.: даже перспективная проекция почему-то не работает (при изменении размеров окна поверхность теряет пропорции), хотя я всё сделал как в туториале, правда в нём матрицу перспективной проекции засовывали прямиком в шейдер, что не очень эффективно, и вычислять это дело стоит на центральном процессоре, а не на графическом. Я пробовал сделать точно также, как в туториале, забив на оптимизацию, но результаты те же самые (надеюсь я не ошибся, когда делал эти изменения. Теперь я вообще ни в чем не уверен)

Comment: Начните рисовать с одного треугольника, потом добавляйте матрицы преобразований и т.д.